# Adding a value from Mongoose DB into a variable in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I am still quite new to Node.js and can't seem to find anything to help me around this.
I am having an issue of getting the query from my last record and adding it to my variable.

If I do it like below: -

```
let lastRecord = Application.find().sort({$natural:-1}).limit(1).then((result) => { result });
```

Then I get the value of the variable showing in console.log as : -

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

What would I need to do to output this correctly to my full data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is it fixed:

```
Application.findOne().sort({$natural:-1}).exec().then((lastRecord) => {
  console.log(lastRecord); // "lastRecord" is the result. You must use it here.
}, (err) => {
  console.log(err); // This only runs if there was an error. "err" contains the data about the error.
});
```

Several things:

1. You are only getting one record, not many records, so you just use `findOne` instead of `find`. As a result you also don't need `limit(1)` anymore.
2. You need to call `.exec()` to actually run the query.
3. The result is returned to you inside the callback function, it must be used here.

`exec()` returns a Promise. A promise in JavaScript is basically just a container that holds a task that will be completed at some point in the future. It has the method `then`, which allows you to bind functions for it to call when it is complete.

Any time you go out to another server to get some data using JavaScript, the code does not stop and wait for the data. It actually continues executing onward without waiting. This is called "asynchronisity". Then it comes back to run the functions given by `then` when the data comes back.

Asynchronous is simply a word used to describe a function that will BEGIN executing when you call it, but the code will continue running onward without waiting for it to complete. This is why we need to provide some kind of function for it to come back and execute later when the data is back. This is called a "callback function".

This is a lot to explain from here, but please go do some research on JavaScript Promises and asynchronisity and this will make a lot more sense.

Edit:

If this is inside a function you can do this:

```
async function someFunc() {
  let lastRecord = await Application.findOne().sort({$natural:-1}).exec();
}
```

Note the word `async` before the function. This must me there in order for `await` to work. However this method is a bit tricky to understand if you don't understand promises already. I'd recommend you start with my first suggestion and work your way up to the `async/await` syntax once you fully understand promises.

Comment: Ok thanks, but excuse my ignorance on this as I am a little shakey on this, but how would you retrieve the result from ouside that callback function? But you're right, I need to research a little further on this

Comment: @JamLizzy101 You don't. This is how JavaScript is supposed to work. You'll have to move whatever logic uses that variable into the callback function.

Comment: Let me try that

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.then()`, you'll want to `await` the record. For example:

`let lastRecord = await Application.find().sort({$natural:-1}).limit(1);`

You can learn more about awaiting promises in the [MDN entry for await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), but the basics are that to use a response from a promise, you either use await or you put your logic into the `.then` statement.

Comment: You don't know if he's inside a function or not so he may need to wrap it in something to put `async` on it. From the looks of it though I don't think they even understand what a Promise is in the first place.